# knockout viewModel: save it on localStrorage and retrive it

Tags: knockout.js

I use knockout to perform various things in a page acording to some data fetched from a web service. User can select certain things afterwards and manipulate data through some select inputs, which affect the knockout's viewModel.

When user finishes changes it continues to the next form (with a POST), which is another web page.

What I would like to do is to store current viewModel in localStorage before it leaves the page, and if he/she presses back, to load the viewModel from the localStorage.

So in my viewModel before user leaves page I do:

```
localStorage.setItem("vM", JSON.stringify(self));
```

then in my frst page I have:

```
var viewModel; viewModel = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("vM"));

if(viewModel == undefined || viewModel == null)  viewModel = new vM();

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

But viewModel is not a valid knockout model after being parsed from json. Is there a way to do this?

thanks

Comment: You either have to create a custom constructor your view model which knows how to build it from JSON or if your view model is simple you can use the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a knockout viewModel is stringified it doesn't serialise cleanly due to the observables, so it can't be deserialised straight back to a valid viewModel.

The best approach would be to use the `ko.json` function to convert your viewmodel to a plain object version which has all the current values. Save this in the localStorage.

Then you would have to initialise your viewModel as normal, and insert the values from your localStorage retrieved object when creating the observables.

More detail can be found in the documentation:
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html

Comment: I tried that. But again I cannot applyBinding to this cached model. I believe because it's of the observable right? So is there a way to save/retrieve a fully function knockout viewModel?

Comment: I don't think so. You would have to translate the values from your cached object into the viewModel's observables and then bind to it as usual. The cached object will not recreate the observable structure.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [knockout.mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) plugin.

Beore saving to `localStorage` call:

```
var unmapped = ko.mapping.toJS(viewModel);
```

To update model with data from the `localStorage` use

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(data, viewModel);
```

Comment: This will not work if you have nested observables (observables in an observable array).